# <p> tag does not show up in nested div layer

Tags: jquery, html, css

My `<p>` tags won't show in a div layer that is nested, and I am not sure if the problem is from 1) my css stylesheet or 2) the way I am generating the `<p>` tags or 3) something else entirely.

my index.html is set up as:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="chart"></div> /* contains an svg */
    <div id="questions"></div> /* contains p tags */
    <div id="tables"></div> /* contains html tables */
  </div>
</div>
```

I have linked a js file to the index page. the js file uses d3 and jquery. in the js file I am trying to make it so that when you click an element of the SVG, the associated text appears in the #questions div layer. the code looks like this:

```
node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
  .on("click", function(d,i) {
    // text = d.data.topics;
    array = d.data.topics;
    var i=1;
    array.forEach(function(question){
      index="q"+i;
      $("#tables").append("<p>"+question[index]+"</p>");        
      i++;
    });
  });
```

what's happening instead is that when you click the element in the SVG, the `<p>` tags are generated and appended to the `#questions` layer, but they are not visible within the `#questions` div layer. the `<p>` tags only show up if they are placed outside of the `#questions` div layer; for example, if I were to append them to the `#container` div layer.

I have a linked css file that styles the div layers as follows:

```
#container {
 width: 1080px;
 height: 800px;
 border: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

#wrapper{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80%;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

#header{
 position: relative;
 height: 20%;
 width: 100%;
}

#chart{
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

#questions{
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 vertical-align: top;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

#tables{
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

#container #wrapper #questions p {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: in all your divs `id` keyword is missing: <div id="container">

Comment: thanks! my actual code does have the `id` keyword. i fixed the mistake here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, sometime ago, I actually solved this by changing the order of the div layers in my index.html file. Instead of including `<div id = "chart">` under `<div id = "wrapper">`, I moved `<div id = "chart"` outside of the `<div id="wrapper">` layer.

```
<body>

 <div id="container">

  <div id="header"></div>

  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="questions"></div>
   <div id="tables"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="chart"></div>

  <script src = "chart2.js"></script>
  <script src = "tables.js"></script>

 </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect `<div="tables'>`.  You need to add `class` or `id`, in your case you would want `<div id="tables">`.   Do this for all of your divs

Comment: thanks for this! i actually mistyped that here, but in my actual code it is correct. will edit!